# Stream audio as if from microphone on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, stream, microphone

How can I stream an audio-file like I can stream input from a microphone?

E.G. When I make a call I want to stream some audio-file to my counterpart.

Comment: A [microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone) acts as an input device. So do you mean stream **from** the microphone or stream **to** the speaker?

Comment: I want to use audio file as microphone input

Comment: "When I make a call I want to stream some audio-file to my counterpart." is not possible. The audio is rerouted to the speaker, if you were to play an audio file, it would necessitate a requirement to play through the speaker, which will fail as it is in use by a call. The audio mechanism operates a flip flop sequence in respect to calls/speaker & microphone.

Comment: This and similar questions has been asked several times already. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432521/background-music-for-call or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024851/redirecting-audio-creating-alternate-sound-paths-in-android/21217919#21217919 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204570/inject-uplink-audio-in-call-with-snapdragon-msm8960-soc