# Streaming voice from phone calls to remote server

Tags: android, audio, mobile, stream, call

I would like to create a solution where I am able to access the phone call's audio stream and stream it real-time to a remote server. I belive there is no official app that would do this to me, and also I guess I will have to use a rooted android to make it possible, so I would like to get some guidance.

It is certain that the android OS has access to the phone call's audio stream, since phone calls in their entireity can be saved via several apps, so I belive streaming it to a server should not be an impossible task.

Since I have no experience in Android development, could anyone give me some information where to start?

P.S.: I know a similar question has been asked before /[Android Phone call stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527930/android-phone-call-stream/), but that thread is over 5 years old.

Comment: `... but that thread is over 5 years old.` and this makes it no longer valid?

Comment: It is about specifically injecting some data into the voice stream, or modyfiing it. I do not wish to do anything like that, I just want to stream it to a remote server.